# Enabling link-time optimizations causes a linker error?

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, lto

I have code which compiles and links fine.

I'm now trying to enable link-time optimizations, but adding `-flto` to my compiler and linker flags is causing a linker error:

```
/usr/local/lib/libboost_thread.a(thread.o): \
    In function `void boost::throw_exception<boost::bad_lexical_cast>(boost::bad_lexical_cast const&)':
    thread.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_16bad_lexical_castEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_16bad_lexical_castEEEvRKT_]+0x124): \
        undefined reference to `vtable for boost::bad_lexical_cast'
```

The only flag I've added is `-flto`.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -flto" )
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} -flto" )
```

To be clear:

- Without `-flto` the app builds and links fine
- With `-flto` (and no other changes), the app fails to link with the above error

What is causing this linker error?

Comment: Same problem here - have you found a solution by now?

Comment: I don't suppose you ever worked this out, did you?

Comment: @JohnIlacqua unfortunately not

Comment: For anyone else finding this question with a similar issue, it seems to me to be a problem in the interaction between LTO and devirtualisation (though I haven't been able to create an MCVE), and is fixed in gcc-8 and onwards.

Comment: Switching g++7 to g++8 fixed my problem with boost and LTO.