# gcc static linking with LTO flag with boost filesystem fails

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, static, lto

boost version 1.64 
gcc version 6.4.1 
Linux OpenSuse x64 42.2 
Cmake 3.5.2

**[linking, no LTO] works:**

```
-std=gnu++11 -O2  -fopenmp -static /opt/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a /opt/lib64/libboost_system.a
```

**[linking, with LTO] does not work:**

```
-std=gnu++11 -O2  -fopenmp -flto=8 -static /opt/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a /opt/lib64/libboost_system.a
```

**error:**

```
/opt/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `boost::filesystem::detail::is_empty(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)':
operations.cpp:(.text+0x536a): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp>'
/opt/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a(operations.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::remove_all_aux(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::filesystem::file_type, boost::system::error_code*)':
operations.cpp:(.text+0x699d): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp>'
operations.cpp:(.text+0x6add): undefined reference to `vtable for boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_imp>'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/zebr.dir/build.make:137: recipe for target 'zebr' failed
```

--> boost libraries compiled with `gcc 6.4.1` and `-std=gnu++11` flag 
--> with `gcc 4.8.5` everything works fine

Comment: Same here with gcc 7.3.0 and boost 1.66.0. Did you find a workaround?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40350936/8360627

Comment: I had a similar issue and ended up only enabling LTO for gcc 8+. Another possible workaround is to add `-fno-devirtualize`, but I'm not sure being able to enable LTO is worth disabling devirtualization.

Comment: Is your Boost compiled with LTO? Also, static libraries (like `/opt/lib64/libboost_filesystem.a`) need gcc-ar when LTO is used.